# Firebase firestore rejecting rules

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

my firestore rules are

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /Runsheets/{RunsheetID} {
  allow read  : if isAuthenticated() && request.auth.uid == resource.data.RunsheetID;
  allow create : if isAuthenticated() && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.RunsheetID;
  allow update, delete: if isAuthenticated() && request.auth.uid == resource.data.RunsheetID ; 
   }
}
}
function isAuthenticated() {

return request.auth != null ;
}
```

I get error When i try to get data with this following code , However i can write the doc

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      console.log("getting Data");
         const q = query(
          collection(db, "Runsheets"),
           where("RunsheetID", "==", User.uid)
        );
      const results = await getDocs(q);
      results.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      });
    };
    getData();
  }, []);
```

the data in my docs has only two fileds

```
const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "Runsheets"), {
        starttime: fixdate(datestr),
        RunsheetID: User.uid,
}
```

the data in data base is stored correctly

```
RunsheetID
"GSZY6HaXSaPzfYowVP04oiLjYG13"
starttime
1656973140
```

User.uid is the uid i got from firebase auth  and is the same as RunsheetID

sorry i am very new to firebase and firestore

Comment: Could you edit the question to show an example of a document that should be readable by this code and rules, and explain in more detail why you think that should be the case?  Also please ensure that `User.uid` contains the user's uid - we can't see that from what you've shown here.

Comment: thanks Dough Stevenson , i have updated the question

Comment: @Blnk Most important thing is missing. What error you are getting ? Use try catch block or `getDocs(q).catch(...)` .